# Optimize Query Join Between Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

3 tables

- WorkRecordfact - has workdate(date) - ~300000 rows
- EmployeeStatus - Startdate(date), EndDate(date), PositionID - 450 Rows
- Positions - PositionID, PositionCode - 10 rows

Queries that look for data in WorkRecordFact filtering by position are taking a long time.  Basic sample Query

```
SELECT workrecordfact.* 
FROM workrecordfact 
INNER JOIN Employeestatus on
  Employeestatus.EmployeeID = workrecordfact.EmployeeID and
  employeestatus.startdate <= workrecordfact.workdate and
  employeestatus.enddate >= workrecordfact.workdate
INNER JOIN Positions on
  employeestatus.PositionID = positions.PositionID
Where workrecordfact.workdate >= '20180601' 
  and workrecordfact.workdate <= '20180930' 
  and PositionCode = 'CSR'
```

Workrecordfact has a clustered index on Workdate

Employeestatus has 4 indexes

- EmployeeID
- EmployeeID+ StartDate
- EmployeeID+ EndDate
- EmployeeID+ StartDate + EndDate

In the query Statistics I'm seeing a lot of 500% elements.  Starting with a Clustered Index Seek on the WorkRecordFact index.  Some numbers that stand out

- Estimated Number of Rows 250
- Estimated Number of Rows to be Read 667
- Number of Executions 381
- Number of Rows Read 49525952??!?!?
- Actual Number of Rows 112018

Results are taking long enough that the .net app sending the query is receiving a timeout in some cases.

I've rebuild/reorganized fragmented indexes, and refreshed statistics but that's not solved the issue.

Any Ideas?

UPDATE:  It seems the query is running quite well from SMSS and only timing out from the application.  Dates are passed in as parameters BTW, currently investigating possible issues with parameter sniffing :-/

Comment: How long is your timeout set for?  Given the sizes of the tables, I'm surprised that it would timeout even *without* indexes.

Comment: Can you attach the execution plan? And are those dates actually literals, or parameters to a proc?

Comment: Add `EmployeeID` index on `workrecordfact`.

Comment: Update:  I actually already have an index on workrecordfact for EmployeeID & Workdate, but it's not being used for this query.  I am also surprised it would time out considering the size of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since workrecordfact has lot more records than EmployeeStatus  and is a date range query.
First indexing them is always a pain.

Secondly Drop indexes on Employee Status they are of no use with regard to this query in my opinion.

```
EmployeeID
EmployeeID+ StartDate
EmployeeID+ EndDate
EmployeeID+ StartDate + EndDate
```

Create one more for EmployeeID on the fact table. 
I think that should help.

Comment: This is what I came up with over the weekend.  But I get back to my desk and discover there actually already is an EmployeeID + workdate index on workrecordfact.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the game is to limit IO on the workrecordfact table.  The way the query and indexing are currently set up, we're scanning 100% of the work in the third quarter, then later filtering that down to just the work of the CSRs.  I wonder if the CSR criteria might be more selective and get us to a lower number of rows read?

This query is pretty zippy, right?

```
SELECT es.EmployeeID, es.StartDate, es.EndDate
FROM Positions p
  JOIN Employeestatus es
  ON p.PositionID = es.PositionID
WHERE PositionCode = 'CSR'
```

'CSR' probably matches exactly one Positions row.  Assuming positions do approximately equal work, we probably only need to read 10% of the Q3 portion of the work table.

Thinking about bringing in the work facts afterwards like this.

```
SELECT w.*
FROM
(
  SELECT es.EmployeeID, es.StartDate, es.EndDate
  FROM Positions p
    JOIN Employeestatus es
    ON p.PositionID = es.PositionID
  WHERE PositionCode = 'CSR'
) es2
  JOIN workrecordfact w
  ON es2.EmployeeID = w.EmployeeID
    AND es2.startdate <= w.workdate AND w.workdate <= es2.enddate
WHERE 
  '2018-06-01' <= w.workdate AND w.workdate <= '2018-09-30'
```

This query would be best supported by this index:

```
CREATE INDEX WorkRecordFact_EmployeeId_WorkDate ON WorkRecordFact(EmployeeId, WorkDate)
```

Moving the conditional choice of workdate logically earlier into the query might be helpful:

```
SELECT w.*
FROM
(
  SELECT es.EmployeeID,
    CASE WHEN es.StartDate <= '2018-06-01' THEN '2018-06-01' ELSE es.StartDate END as StartDate,
    CASE WHEN '2018-09-30' <= es.EndDate THEN '2018-09-30' ELSE es.EndDate END as EndDate
  FROM Positions p
    JOIN Employeestatus es
    ON p.PositionID = es.PositionID
  WHERE PositionCode = 'CSR'
) es2
  JOIN workrecordfact w
  ON es2.EmployeeID = w.EmployeeID
    AND es2.startdate <= w.workdate AND w.workdate <= es2.enddate
```

Comment: This query ends up with the exact same query plan as the original.